# Component not updating in react native redux app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have **two components who use the same reducer and share the same state**.

- The first one is a form, the second one is a separate component to
  update a specific field of that form using
  *react-native-autocomplete-select*.
- In the second component, everything works fine. But when I get back
  to the first component (the form), the prop that I'm updating in the
  second component is now undefined. **Only when I leave the component
  and come back to it or reload my app does the component display the
  correct value.**

I'm new to redux and I thought I had figured it out but apparently, I'm still missing something.

I'll try to share as much code as possible in order to make it easy for anyone to help me out but let me know if you want me to share additional code.

I would really like to understand what's going on.

**First Component**

```
class EditElem extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.xFetch();
  }

  onButtonPress() {
    const { name, description, elem_id } = this.props;

    this.props.xSave({ name, description, elem_id });
  }

  render() {

    return (
        <ScrollView>
          <View>
            <Text>Information</Text>
            <CardSection>
              <Input
                label="Name"
                placeholder="..."
                value={this.props.name}
                onChangeText={value => this.props.xUpdate({ prop: 'name', value })}
              />
              <Text style={styles.labelStyle}>Description</Text>
              <Input
                placeholder="Write here..."
                value={this.props.description}
                onChangeText={value => this.props.xUpdate({ prop: 'description', value })}
                multiline = {true}
                numberOfLines = {4}
              />
              <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={ () => Actions.selectElem() }>
                <View style={styles.wrapperStyle}>
                  <View style={styles.containerStyle}>
                    <Text style={styles.labelStyle}>Elem</Text>
                    <Text adjustsFontSizeToFit style={styles.inputStyle}>{checkElem(this.props.elem_id ? this.props.elem_id.toString() : "0")}</Text>
                  </View>
                </View>
              </TouchableWithoutFeedback>

            </CardSection>

            <Button title="Save Changes" onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)} />
          </View>
        </ScrollView>

    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const { name, description, elem_id } = state.x.x;

  return { name, description, elem_id };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { xUpdate, xFetch, xSave })(EditElem);
```

**Second Component**

```
class SelectElem extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.xFetch();
  }

  saveElem(suggestion) {
    let elem_id = suggestion.id;
    let text = suggestion.text

    this.props.xUpdate({ prop: 'elem', text })
    this.props.xUpdate({ prop: 'elem_id', elem_id })

    this.props.xSave({ elem_id });
  }

  render() {

    const suggestions = data

    const onSelect = (suggestion) => {
      this.saveElem(suggestion);
    }

    return(
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <AutoComplete
          placeholder={checkElem(this.props.elem_id ? this.props.elem_id.toString() : "0")}
          onSelect={onSelect}
          suggestions={suggestions}
          suggestionObjectTextProperty='text'
          value={this.props.elem}
          onChangeText={value => this.props.xUpdate({ prop: 'elem', value })}
          minimumSimilarityScore={0.4}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const { elem_id, description, name, elem } = state.x.x;
  return { elem_id, description, name, elem };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { xUpdate, xFetch, xSave })(SelectElem);
```

**store**

```
const store = createStore(reducers, {}, compose(applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk)));
```

**reducer**

```
export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_X:
      return { ...state, x: { ...state.x, name: action.payload.name, description: action.payload.description, elem_id: action.payload.elem_id } };
    case UPDATE_X:
      return { ...state, x: { ...state.x, [action.payload.prop]: action.payload.value }};
    case SAVE_X:
      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**Actions**

```
export const xUpdate = ({ prop, value }) => {
  return {
    type: UPDATE_X,
    payload: { prop, value }
  };
};

export const xSave = ({ name, description, elem_id }) => {

  return (dispatch) => {
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'https:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      data: {_____________________ }

      }
    }).then(response => {
      dispatch({ type: SAVE_X });
    }).catch(error => console.log(error))
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if UPDATE_X, SAVE_X ... are defined? Do you have the right import statement at the top of the file?

Comment: Yes they are, I haven't included them to not overload the code but everything is working fine.I'm using the same actions and reducer for the form in component one and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so my problem came from my reducer actualy in my SAVE_X:

I had:

```
case SAVE_X:
      return { state };
```

Instead of this:

```
case SAVE_X:
      return { ...state, elem: { ...state.elem, elem_id: action.payload.elem_id } };
```